# I'm unsure of how to add images from an RSS feed into my UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, rss, feed

I have an rss feed appearing correctly in my `UITableView` however I'm trying to add the images from the `RSS` feed. Below is the code I'm using. I've removed my attempts to incorporate the images so far and just left title and link. Any help much appreciated.

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {
        NSXMLParser *parser;
        NSMutableArray *feeds;
        NSMutableDictionary *item;
        NSMutableString *title;
        NSMutableString *link;
        NSString *element;
}

@end

@implementation MasterViewController


- (void)awakeFromNib
 {
        [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://art-britain.co.uk/category/galleries/feed/"];
        parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [parser setDelegate:self];
        [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
        [parser parse];
    }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return feeds.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];
        return cell;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

        element = elementName;

        if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

            item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            title   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            link   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

            [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
            [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];

            [feeds addObject:[item copy]];

        }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

        if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
            [title appendString:string];
        } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
            [link appendString:string];
        }

}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

        [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"link"];
            [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];

        }
}

@end
```

Comment: You didn't describe the where is the problem..

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to this, I have tried a few different ways to incorporate images from my rss feed into the table view however they've all been unsuccessful. So I'm wondering if anyone can advise how best to incorporate images into the code above?

Comment: A very good approach is the LazyTableImages https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html provided by Apple, and working with `RSS` in a way that you want.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I've taken a look at the LazyTableImages as I'm still struggling to work with my code however I can't get the reader to work with my xml file here: http://art-britain.co.uk/category/galleries/feed/ any advice much appreciated! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`RSS` `XML` will contain a image object declared like this:

```
<image>
    <url>http://www.w3schools.com/images/logo.gif</url>
    <title>W3Schools.com</title>
    <link>http://www.w3schools.com</link>
</image>
```

What you need to extract is the `URL` of the image.

Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` start download of the image:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   ... your code

    __weak UITableViewCell *weakCell = cell;

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^
    {
        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:YOUR_EXTRACTED_URL];

        if (imgData) 
        {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];

            if (image) 
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                {
                    cell.imageView.image = image;
                });
            }
        }
    });

    return cell;
}
```

And define the kBgQueue:

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
```

Comment: thanks very much, I've used your suggested code and at the moment I'm getting a undeclared identifier error for 'kBgQueue' which I'm not sure how to fix?

Comment: Sorry dude, I forgot to post one line. I updated my answer. Check if it works now :)

Comment: no problem, thanks again. So this is what I have for the NSData line: `NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"http://art-britain.co.uk/category/galleries/feed/"]` this is giving me an 'incompatible pointer' warning and the app crashes once built.

Comment: You have to create a `NSURL` object using `[NSURL URLWithString:@"art-britain.co.uk/category/galleries/feed/"]` and pass it there.